# InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [defau lt] [App/Message].'

Tags: php, laravel

I can't seed messages in my database. I tried serveral solutions and none of them worked.

```
Psy Shell v0.9.12 (PHP 7.1.29 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> factory(App\Message::class, 150)->create();
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [defau
lt] [App/Message].'
```

I'm using Laravel.

This is UserFactory.php.

```
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    use Faker\Generator as Faker;



    $factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
        return [
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
            'profile_image' =>'http://via.placeholder.com/150x150',
            'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    });

    $factory->define(Message::class, function (Faker $faker) {
      do{
        $from = rand(1, 15);
        $to = rand(1, 15);
      } while ($from == $to);


        return [
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
            'text' => $faker->sentence,

        ];
    });
```

I have also tried by using:
    $factory->define(Message::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker)
And still don't works.

Comment: Forgot to `use App\Message;` at the top?

Comment: Worked!! thank you.